# How can I fix this sentence tokenization code to keep quotation marks from migrating to the following sentence in the output?

Tags: python, tokenize, text-mining

I am trying to scrape the text from pdfs into an excel spreadsheet- specifically I want to tokenize these stories into sentences.

I have it mostly worked out but in cases where one sentence ends in a closing quotation mark and the next sentence starts on a new paragraph/ new page, the closing quotation migrates to the following sentence instead of staying with the preceding sentence. For example with the following text: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6d3Cg.png)

The quotation after makeve!” gets carried onto the next sentence on the next page. So it looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0USui.png).

How can I alter my code so this doesn't happen?

Here is my code:

```
import pdfplumber
import pandas as pd
import nltk
import re
import glob

def exclude_page_numbers(page_text, page_elements, exclusion_regions):
    filtered_text = ""

    for element in page_elements:
        text = element["text"]
        x, y = element["x0"], element["top"]  # Get the x and y coordinates of the element

        # Check if the element falls within any exclusion region
        exclude = False
        for region in exclusion_regions:
            x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max = region
            if x_min <= x <= x_max and y_min <= y <= y_max:
                exclude = True
                break

        if not exclude and not any(char.isdigit() for char in text) and not text.strip().isdigit():
            filtered_text += text + " "  # Add a space after each element

    return filtered_text


def extract_sentences(text):
    # Split text on occurrences of `.`, `!`, or `?` while considering quotation marks within the sentence
    sentences = re.split(r'(?<=[.!?])(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)', text)
    sentences = [sentence.strip() for sentence in sentences]

    # Merge the closing quotation mark with the preceding sentence (this doesn't work as intended)
    merged_sentences = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(sentences):
        if sentences[i].endswith('"'):
            if i + 1 < len(sentences):
                merged_sentence = sentences[i] + ' ' + sentences[i + 1]
                merged_sentences.append(merged_sentence)
                i += 2
            else:
                merged_sentences.append(sentences[i])
                i += 1
        else:
            merged_sentences.append(sentences[i])
            i += 1

    # Tokenize merged sentences using nltk.sent_tokenize
    tokenized_sentences = []
    for sentence in merged_sentences:
        tokenized_sentences.extend(nltk.sent_tokenize(sentence))

    return tokenized_sentences

def extract_text_from_pdf(pdf_file_path):
    with pdfplumber.open(pdf_file_path) as pdf:
        num_pages = len(pdf.pages)
        text = ""
        for page in range(3, num_pages - 2):
            page_obj = pdf.pages[page]
            page_text = page_obj.extract_text()
            page_elements = page_obj.extract_words()  # Obtain the text elements and their positions
            filtered_text = exclude_page_numbers(page_text, page_elements, exclusion_regions)
            text += filtered_text

        return text

def scrape_sentences_to_excel(pdf_file_paths, excel_file_path):
    sentences = []
    for pdf_file_path in pdf_file_paths:
        # Extract text from PDF
        pdf_text = extract_text_from_pdf(pdf_file_path)

        # Extract sentences from the text
        extracted_sentences = extract_sentences(pdf_text)
        sentences.extend(extracted_sentences)

    # Create a pandas DataFrame with a single column for sentences
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Sentences': sentences})

    # Write the DataFrame to an Excel file
    df.to_excel(excel_file_path, index=False)

    print("Sentences extracted and saved to Excel successfully!")



pdf_folder_path = 'my_pdf_file_path'  # Folder path containing PDFs
excel_file_path = 'me_excel_file_path'  # Output Excel file path

# Specify the exclusion regions as (x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max)
exclusion_regions = [(42, 558, 359, 559)]  # Add your exclusion regions here

# Get a list of PDF files in the folder
pdf_file_paths = glob.glob(pdf_folder_path + '/*.pdf')

# Scrape sentences from PDFs and save to Excel
scrape_sentences_to_excel(pdf_file_paths, excel_file_path)
```

Comment: Note: I just had to replace the curly quotation marks with straight ones and it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression that you currently use contains `"`, a straight double quote. It seems the extracted text in the pdf contains curly quotes `“` (left/open) and `”` (right/close), which are different characters that are not captured by the regular expression.

If the pdfs are guaranteed to use this type of quotes then that would make the task (and therefore the regex) considerably easier, because then you only need to match on the closing quote and then merge it back, without using any lookahead/lookbehind that complicate the original expression.

MCVE:

```
import re

def extract_sentences(text):
    # Split text on occurrences of `.`, `!`, or `?` followed by optional closing quote
    sentences = re.split(r'([.!?]”?)', text)
    sentences = [sentence.strip() for sentence in sentences]

    merged_sentences = []
    for i in range(len(sentences)):
        # check if sentence is just [.!?] followed by optional quote
        # if yes then concatenate with previous sentence
        if re.search(r'^[.!?]”?$', sentences[i]) and i > 0:
            merged_sentences[len(merged_sentences)-1] += sentences[i]
        else:
            merged_sentences.append(sentences[i])
    return merged_sentences
    
text = """Yimbi yawa kumhlaba olungileyo, yakhula, yathwala isiqhamo ngokuphindwe kalikhulu.

Etshilo ke wadanduluka esithi: “Oneendlebe zokuva makeve!”

Ke abafundi bakaYesu bambuza besithi:"""

print(extract_sentences(text))
```

Result (formatted for clarity):

```
['Yimbi yawa kumhlaba olungileyo, yakhula, yathwala isiqhamo ngokuphindwe kalikhulu.',
 'Etshilo ke wadanduluka esithi: “Oneendlebe zokuva makeve!”',
 'Ke abafundi bakaYesu bambuza besithi:']
```

Comment: Thank you! I just figured that out now! explains why it was working for some of the texts and not others.